# HttpUrlConnection read inputstream - different output result

Tags: java, character-encoding, inputstream, httpurlconnection

Below method is designed to get source code of html page of given url, but it returns result in different charset in each call (in every call argument `url` is same), please, explain me why?

```
private String getSourceCode(URL url) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel MacOS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");

    return IOUtils.toString(conn.getInputStream()); 
}
```

Comment: the remote site has a sense of humor.

Comment: maybe :) when I check response contect type charset is always UTF-8, but result is different...

Comment: Can you check what is the difference in the output?

Comment: **first call**: `...y??????Ywmm?Vs??B?0?/M??gJ?l?p.??n.??pBo??N...`    **second call**: _normal html code_     **url**: `http://habrahabr.ru/post/266163/`

Comment: difference is in output string encoding, but I don't know why its different at each call

Comment: If the data is binary you shouldn't be converting it to a String in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are several possible reasons. For example behind the URL there can actually be several different servers with different default encoding of response. First call can be served by server with utf-8, the other can be served by another server with another encoding.